# Jquery on Paste Text as if it was typed

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, autocomplete, paste

stackoverflowers. I'm working on an autocomplete app that needs to capture the input text character by character, and I'm currently listening to the "input" event with jquery.

The issue I'm facing is with pasted text, since the function is triggered with the whole input value, like this:

Pasted value = "demo"

```
input.val() = "demo"
```

But, what I'm looking to achieve is to decompose that pasted value as if it was actually typed in, and trigger the function 4 times like this:

Pasted value = "demo"

```
input.val() = "d"
input.val() = "de"
input.val() = "dem"
input.val() = "demo"
```

Could you guys give me any tips or directions on how to solve this issue with vanilla JS or Jquery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try following approach:

```
<input type="text">
<div></div>

<script> 
  var myInput = $("input");
  var value = ''; //to store previous input value

  myInput.on('input', function () {
    var current = myInput.val();
    var dif = current.replace(value, '');
    if(dif.length) {
      var out = value;
      for(var i = 0; i < dif.length; i++) {
        out += dif.substr(i, 1);
        output(out);
      }
    }
    value = current;
  });

  function output(text) {
    console.log(text);
    $("div").text(text);
    // here you can even to re-set input value via myInput.val
  }
</script>
```

Try to input "1", "2", "345" and you will get "1", "12", "123", "1234", "12345" in the console log.

This approach would work only when you append text to the end of the input. If you need to insert text not only to the end of the input, the procedure should be updated.

See also [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2tW0GQ?p=info).

Comment: I'm already using it, but I need to capture the pasted text before the oninput is triggered.

I'm currently trying to solve it by preventing the default behaviour on the onpaste event, so that I can separate it from the oninput trigger.

Comment: @moy2010 I updated the answer and provided a solution draft. It does not cover all cases, but the idea should be clear enough. The `output` method is being called per each symbol in the input, no matter how it is added (one by one or in group).

Comment: Thanks for your help, dhilt! the "out" variable returned by your for loop does actually what I wanted, but for some reason the typeWatch plugin doesn't recognize the changes in the input field value (I'm populating the field value with the content of "out").

I will have to keep trying and learn from your sample code.

Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check the length of input before display it to the screen.